# battery meter problem with Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, laptop, netbook, battery

I am running Windows 7 Ultimate RTM on an ASUS N10E notebook. The native driver detection went very well, except for the fact that it does not recognize the state of the battery charge. The tray icon always shows 100% charge until the battery runs out, at which point the laptop suddenly dies with no warning whatsoever.

Does anyone know what driver I should install to rectify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this by:

- installing the chipset driver (*Inf Update for Vista*) using vista compatibility mode, and then
- installing the *ATK0100 Utility for Vista* using vista compatibility mode

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a BIOS problem. Usually, Windows tells you if it can't read the battery state. Did the battery indicator work before?